# Best way to extract values from strings (regexp?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

I'm working with an app (Ruby 1.9.2, Rails 3) and an API and need interface an API given certain param values.

What's the best way to break this:

```
bedrooms: 3 - 7
bathrooms: 1 - 8
sqft: 1000 - 8000
price: $100000 - $800000
```

Into this:

```
bedrooms_min = 3
bedrooms_max = 7
bathrooms_min = 1
bathrooms_max = 8
sqft_min = 1000
sqft_max = 8000
price_min = 100000
price_max = 800000
```

Comment: Should the end result be a new string containing 8 lines, as in your question, or some assignments to local variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
price_input = "$100000 - $800000"
price_min, price_max = price_input.gsub(/[^\d-]/, '').split('-', 2).map(&:to_i)
price_min # 100000
price_max # 800000
```

So, basically we remove everything except digits and '-' sign that separates two values and then split string in two by this separator.